# Android Studio: Files are edited without my intervention

Tags: android, android-studio

I was watching around for a bug and one solution says to do: "File > Invalidate Caches and Restart"

But then I find my `build.gradle` replaced with unknown data.

Later I replaced it again with "previous" data. And again did the same "File > Invalidate Caches and Restart"

Now, my `activity_main.xml` file got replaced with this:

```
<component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.3@jar">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.support.constraint/constraint-layout-solver/1.1.3/bde0667d7414c16ed62d3cfe993cff7f9d732373/constraint-layout-solver-1.1.3.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

What triggered this? I lost my XML code here.

Comment: Do you have a source control for your source codes? It will be easier to detect this problem if you have one.

Comment: Nope. I haven't used one for this. I just started learning this.

Comment: I suggest use one as early as possible such as Bitbucket, gitlab or github. In that way, you won't lose any code.  TBH, i don't know what caused your problem. "File > Invalidate Caches and Restart" does not fix that problem.

Comment: I'll always experience the same nasty problem whenever I'm using Windows. Never experience the problem when I'm suing either Linux or MacOS.

Comment: I also faced this problem multiple times. But last time I checked, what I vaguely remember that if you open the file in Windows, not in Android studio, you will probably find the file is still ok. Would you check that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though the files within Android Studio appeared to be modified and filled with some garbage, I was able to open them with other editors and the data is still there.

Windows users, don't do this: `"File > Invalidate Caches and Restart"`

I have not found a way to restore this in Android Studio. But was able to copy and paste the file data from another editor and make it work.

Comment: Vishrut Mavani's answer helped me even after I've done `File > Invalidate Caches and Restart`. And yes, you are right, files's data is still there.

Answer (score 7):

**I have tried below solution and its work for me.**

I have delete the caches folder from C: Drive. after an open project in an Android studio.

C:\Users\admin.AndroidStudio3.3\system\caches

Comment: For me the Android Studio folder was in me user directory instead of admins also i m running Android Studio 3.5. But deleting the caches folder and restarting android studio works like a charm :)