# Android Studio broken .studio instead of classes shows incomprehensible pieces – xml

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

I started the studio and see such a picture, considering that all the classes are broken and everything is lit in red - the project is going and working. Help me fix it. Invalidate does not help. Instead of classes in general pieces of markup ...[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like your XML has slipped into your Java classes

Comment: you cant write .xml code into java files

Comment: i know. studio instead of classes shows incomprehensible pieces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have delete caches folder from C: Drive. after open project in an Android studio.

C:\Users\admin.AndroidStudio3.3\system\caches

[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55253274/8211160)

Answer (score 1):

1. Close Project
2. Try Removing **.idea folder** from your project.
3. Restart your project again in android studio

Comment: i know. studio instead of classes shows incomprehensible pieces –

Comment: Then..
1. Close Project

2. Try Removing **.idea folder** from your project.

3. Restart your project again in android studio